# remove div tags from textbox

Tags: development, sharepoint-enterprise

Any clue why i get the output in my textbox_moreinformation look like this?:

COLUMN VALUE

I'm working with two webparts, the provder webparts values i want to display on my consumer, and i only want my output to contain the column value, not the div tags!

Code in provder, button_edit:

```
    protected void Button_Edit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
        if (ListBox_List.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            WP_ConsumerSearchListUserControl control = (WP_ConsumerSearchListUserControl)Page.LoadControl(@"~/_CONTROLTEMPLATES/Kingen.Artifacts.WebParts/WP_ConsumerSearchList/WP_ConsumerSearchListUserControl.ascx");
            control.GetProduct(ListBox_List.SelectedValue);
            Controls.Add(control);
        }
    }
```

In my consumer...ascx:

```
    public void GetProduct(string prodNum)
    {
        SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
        SPList prodList = web.Lists.TryGetList("Extern Products");

        if (prodList != null)
        {
            SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
            query.Query =
                string.Format(
                    "<Where><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='ProductNumber' /><Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value></BeginsWith></Where>",
                    prodNum);
            query.ViewFields = "";

            SPListItemCollection items = prodList.GetItems(query);

            foreach (SPListItem listItem in items)
            {
                TextBox_NameList.Text = listItem["Title"] !=null ? listItem["Title"].ToString() : string.Empty;
                TextBox_ListPriceList.Text = listItem["ListPrice"] !=null ? listItem["ListPrice"].ToString() : string.Empty;
                TextBox_ProdNumList.Text = listItem["ProductNumber"] != null ? listItem["ProductNumber"].ToString() : string.Empty;
                TextBox_ColorList.Text = listItem["Color"] !=null ? listItem["Color"].ToString() : string.Empty;
                TextBox_MoreInformationList.Text = listItem["MoreInformation"] !=null  ? listItem["MoreInformation"].ToString() : string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
```

Kind regards,
Kristian

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the `MoreInformation` column is a RichText field. If yes, you might want to try the way is described on this [blogpost](http://www.thesharepointblog.net/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=815f255a-d0ef-4258-be2a-28487dc9975c&ID=30).

I find it pretty clear, but if you need more help, please feel free to ask.

I hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Nobert's URL will solve the issue but generally I use [SharePoint:InputFormTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.inputformtextbox.aspx) control to show multi-line text field in Visual Web Parts!

And usually there is a problem that you cannot change the width of this control, so you can do it using CSS as described in [my blog post](http://arsalkhatri.wordpress.com/2011/03/16/rich-text-box-in-share-point-2010/)

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I changed my column to **"Plain text"** and it works well now :)

Comment: Well, this is also a solution, but you are loosing functionality too.